# Hyperledger Fabric Peer Connection error with Orderer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, grpc

I am trying to connect the peer with the orderer in the local machine.
Here is what I have done so far.

I started the Orderer after starting the Fabric CA Server

```
export ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
export ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
export ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
export ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
export ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=192.168.2.103
export ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
export ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
export ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
export ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric
export ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
orderer
```

Then I am trying to start the fabric peer using this command.

```
 export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
 export CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
 export CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
 export CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
 export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
 export CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
 export CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
 export CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
 export CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
 export CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
 export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric
 export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
 export CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
```

I already copied the necessary files to the required directory as experter above after that I ran the command `peer node start`
This command is giving me error

> 2017-12-26 18:22:47.613 IST [deliveryClient] connect -> DEBU 32e
>   Connected to  2017-12-26 18:22:47.613 IST [deliveryClient] connect ->
>   ERRO 32f Failed obtaining connection: Could not connect to any of the
>   endpoints: [orderer.example.com:7050] 2017-12-26 18:22:47.614 IST
>   [deliveryClient] try -> WARN 330 Got error: Could not connect to any
>   of the endpoints: [orderer.example.com:7050] ,at 8 attempt. Retrying
>   in 2m8s

On the orderer side I am getting this

> 2017-12-26 18:24:55.617 IST [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 191 grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "192.168.2.103:56580": EOF

Can anyone tell What i am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Are you running your env. inside the docker?

Comment: No. I AM running on local machine

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem in your case is that you are trying to use configuration transaction produced for `fabric-sample` which encodes ordering service endpoint to be `orderer.example.com:7050` while running you local machine this address is not reachable. So as an easy solution to this you can extend your `/etc/hosts` file and make `orderer.example.com` domain name to point on your localhost. Second option would be to change ordering service endpoint within config transaction, e.g. `configtx.yaml`:

```
################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Orderer
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for orderer related parameters
#
################################################################################
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    # Available types are "solo" and "kafka"
    OrdererType: solo

    Addresses:
        - localhost:7050

    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 2s

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
        MaxMessageCount: 10

        # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 98 MB

        # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
        # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    Kafka:
        # Brokers: A list of Kafka brokers to which the orderer connects
        # NOTE: Use IP:port notation
        Brokers:
            - 127.0.0.1:9092

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the orderer side of the network
    Organizations:
```

Basically you need to change following line:

```
    Addresses:
        - PUT_HERE_CORRECT_IP_ADDRESS:7050
```

Next you need to run `configtxgen` tool to get updated configuration transaction block.

Comment: HI Thankyou so much for the answer but i already updated the /etc/hosts for the same
now i am getting this error after updating the congs
`Principal deserialization failure (The supplied identity is not valid, Verify() returned x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.org1.example.com")) for identity `
Can you take a look?

Comment: In your configuration you missed setup of your MSP folder with all peer crypto material, e.g. you need `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH` to point to the right location.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have had that it was incorrect certs. Last time it took me half a day to find I had copied peer1.org1 certs into peer1.org2 folder on an orderer. (For me, org2 is a different CA server). Once I had 1 wrong MSPDir path in the configtx.yaml used to create the channel block.